# Can i change a static text in a Dialog after window came up in vc++ mfc application?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am initialising a Dialog by using OnInitDialog and i initialized a static text as "loading"

now i had a function after it returns static text should change from "loading" to "initialized".

is this possible??

can text change even after a dialog came up??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of course it can. But you will have to change its ID to something other than IDC_STATIC. Then, you can use it like any other control.

Personally, I would create a control variable from it, and do

`m_MyStatic.SetWindowText(L"Initialized");`

(Not really. I would store the string in the STRINGTABLE and load it from there, buy you get the idea)

Comment: in which method can i call this statement.   
Dialog open only when OnInitDialog function returns and where can i use this statement as my progam has no running methods now.

Comment: Wherever you want to change the text. Like after the function that initializes what you are initializing returns successfully

Comment: when OnInitDialog returns,i dont have any running method in my program as it started with calling OnInitDialog.

I have some other methods for Button Clicks

Comment: What does "initialized" mean? What are you initializing? If it's just the dialog, it makes no sense to change the text, since the dialog will not show until you've exited OnInitDialog, so if you see the dialog, it is initialized. If you want to initialize something but show the dialog while the initialization takes place, you'll need another thread. When the thread notifies it has finished successfully, you can change the text.

Comment: I just said that as an example,actually i am searching all COM ports to find my device, which is time taking if i call this in OnInitDialog, it will take so much time and my dialog will not load as OnInitDialog method is not returned,so i called it as a seperate thread,but i want to change the static text in the dialog when the thread returns.

Comment: Ok, then. Who creates the thread? The dialog? Or the same who creates the dialog? If it's the dialog, when the thread finishes it can notify the dialog, and it can update the text then. But if the one who creates the thread also creates the dialog, and the dialog is modal, I'm not so sure how it can be done. The dialog would be in its modal loop and the owner wouldn't have much chance to do anything...